# I have here a schema of a BJT with a speed up capacitance, but I can't seem to grasp why is there a connection to a negative voltage

Tags: bjt

[image: The circuit in question]

I am a student and learning analog and digital circuits. As I was studying I came across this schema.
I have here the circuit. As you can see, there is a connection to Eb=-1V from the base terminal of the BJT. My question is what purpose does it serve? I figured it might be to help drain the capacitor faster when the VIN switches down to 0, but I can't really seem to find any explanation as to why that resistance exists. All schemas related to speed up capacitance BJT that I could find on the internet do not have that resistance. I was hoping I could get some guidance here. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any info you can share regarding the expected range of Vin and the circuit's intended purpose?

Comment: are you familiar with the concept of voltage dividers? If that's the case, look at R1 + RB. Do with C1 what you usually do when there's a constant voltage involved – ignore it for now.

Comment: This is a schema from my lab detailing an inverter made with a bipolar transistor. The expected range of Vin is between 0V and 5V. It was presented to us with the following *brief* explanations which consisted of this: "If VIN is 0V, corresponding to 0 logic level, Q1 transistor is off and VOUT voltage will have 5V value, corresponding to 1 logical level. If VIN is 5V, corresponding to 1 logical level, Q1 transistor is on and VOUT voltage will have 0,2V value, corresponding to 0 logic level."

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have looked up voltage dividers. I understood the overall idea of how it would work, but I am still confused about why we need to divide the voltage there and why we used an negative potential Eb=-1.

Comment: @ChristianNitas we can't tell you this – a circuit like this never makes sense on its own, it's embedded in something else and fulfills a purpose.

Comment: It seems one of those inverter circuits used to test the switching time of a BJT: if it is so, the negative base bias is used to sink out of the base the stored charge in order to speed up the turn-off transition of the BJT, decreasing both the storage time \$t_\text{s}\$ and the fall time \$t_f\$ (and thus the Off time since \$t_\text{OFF}=t_\text{s}+t_f\$.

Comment: why would you need to grasp the reason for the negative voltage? ... all you need to grasp is the effect of the negative voltage on the operation of the circuit

Comment: @ChristianNitas Oh, geez. This is just an RTL inverter. What do you need to know? There's a reason for everything there, including the negative rail.

Comment: @ChristianNitas It's been a while and you've ignored this. There are some good elements to the question, but perhaps you are past caring. I believe you were talking about what's called a "speed-up" capacitor. When pulled high from the left side, it rapidly drags upward on the BJT base, which more quickly causes it to pull down on the collector. That's countered by the BJT BC charge storage, but if designed to be just the right size the capacitor is useful here. (Sometimes a resistor is put in series, too.) You can work out what happens when the input pulls now in a downward direction.